# Getting a weighted proportion in R

Tags: r

I have created a transition probability matrix using 3 states (A,B,C) as follows:

```
  transition <-prop.table(with(data, table(data$old, 
               data$new)), 2)
```

For example, if you wanted to get the probability for A --> B, you would count the number of times you see B follow A and divide it by the number of times you see any state follow A. Now suppose that there is a certain weight/importance associated with each of the rows of data. How would I modify the above to get a weighted probability transition matrix?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this...

```
transition <- prop.table(tapply(data$weight, list(data$old, data$new), sum), 2)
```

where `data$weight` is a column of weights for each row of data.

The `tapply` with `length` will reproduce what you have.  Changing it to `sum` adds the weights for each combination rather than just counting them.